# How do I code a command, that has a variable set by a user defined parameter?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

For example, if I have a command where the Discord bot sends a message when a user gets a role, how do I code the command so that server mods or admins can use a slash command to then define the actual role that the bot will react to, as opposed to hard coding the role? I'm using Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .json or even a .txt to store the variable then read it from there.

Json:

```
import json
@bot.tree.command(name="changevar")
async def changevar(interaction:discord.Interaction, var:str):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Saving var...", ephemeral=True)
    data = {
        "var":var
    }
    path = "YOUR_PATH"
    with open("{path}\\var.json","w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
        json.dump(data,file)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content="Variable changed.")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.content.startswith("var"):
        path = "YOUR_PATH"
        with open(f"{path}\\var.json","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            var = data["var"]
        await message.channel.send(var)
    else:
        pass
```

Txt:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="changevar2")
async def changevar2(interaction:discord.Interaction, var:str):
    await interaction.response.send_message("Saving var...", ephemeral=True)
    path = "YOUR_PATH"
    with open(f"{path}\\variable.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
         file.write(var)
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content="Variable changed.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.content.startswith("vartxt"):
        path = "YOUR_PATH"
        with open(f"{path}\\variable.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            var = file.read()
        await message.channel.send(var)
    else:
        pass
```

In .json you can easily save multiple vars in one file, and it is easier to access. You can create more complex systems with it like an economy system or something like that. So I recommend the .json but for this .txt is good too.